# 2-step Authentication Facebook - Is it possible to disable SMS codes?

Tags: facebook, security, authentication

I have Facebook login approvals set up. Is there any way to stop Facebook from sending login codes via SMS? Preferably, I'd like to exclusively use my Google Authenticator app to receive login codes.

I use MightyText to sync my texts to my computer (and their servers), and therefore my login codes get synced as well. If MightyText gets hacked, it could jeopardise my 2 step authentication.

Edit in response to answer: After disabling and then enabling facebook's login approvals, I still receive text messages. There doesn't seem to be a way to remove text messaging as an option. [image: Facebook's Security Section]

Answer (score 3):

You can switch to Google Authenticator based code generation from [Security Settings → Code generator](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=security&section=code_generator&view) menu.

[image: Code generator]

Click on *Set up another way to get security codes*, it'll guide you to setting up Google Authenticator for code generation

Comment: I have added Google authenticator. When I try to log into Facebook from a new computer, I am still sent a sms. My question asked if I can disable sms code generation and exclusively use my Google authenticator app.

Comment: Looks like you haven't set it right. The screenshot you see is what I've set up and i don't get an SMS

Comment: How would I set it up wrong? I enable login approvals and I enable Google Authenticator as described in your post.

Answer (score 2):

When you first setup, you will have two codes:

1. from SMS on your mobile (because you had to list your mobile to enable login security)
2. from your code generator app (from the FB mobile app or a third party code generator)

You will find that both these codes will work.

Now we will disable login code being sent to sms (mobile).

Next time you login to Facebook, remove your mobile number from Settings - Mobile. Now you will no longer get SMS from Facebook. Just use your preferred code generator app.

Comment: This does of course work, but it's a bit sad that one has to completely remove the phone number for this instead of just being able to prioritise a code generator. I'd have thought that Facebook would also have a financial incentive to not send out millions of text messages people don't need.

Comment: This does _not_ work. Facebook turns off 2FA when the phone number is removed from Settings → Mobile. When attempting to turn 2FA back on, Facebook says _You must add either a phone or both security key and code generator in order to turn on two-factor authentication._

Answer (score 1):

Facebook currently (May 2017) requires either "Text Message" (SMS) or "Security Key" (U2F hardware token) to be enabled as a backup second factor in order to use 2FA. If you have a hardware token, and a browser that supports it, you can add it as a factor. Once it's set up, you can disable SMS verification.